# I can't seem to update Ubuntu; Software Updater is blank

Tags: package-management, software-center, update-manager

Ubuntu Software Updater is blank when opened.

[image: top of Software Updater window, completely blank]

I also can't update through Ubuntu Updates in the Ubuntu Software application.

I could use the terminal but then I would have to type in my password, which I don't normally have to do for updating, and seeing as it is playing up, I guess would this be a security risk.

I have tried to remove/uninstall Software Updater but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appstream/+bug/1583862) for the moment, the cpu also runs at 100% with this bug.

A quick fix is, open the program named `software & updates` uncheck unsupported updates(xenial-backports).

This fixes the problem for now.