# CPU usage 100% at runing every application

Tags: gnome, cpu, mate, process, cpu-load

Whenever the application starts executing(running) the CPU usage touch 100%, and stuck(hanged) the system for some minutes. Even a light text editor CPU usage is 100%.

```
%CPU     COMMAND
 143     unity-settings
 102     Firefox
```

and when an application interface is shown on screen then CPU usage is normal.

Comment: this might be related to this problem https://askubuntu.com/questions/775106/i-cant-seem-to-update-ubuntu-software-updater-is-blank/775179#775179

Comment: I try this but have same problem